# How to generate sum report from joining of 2 tables where the join key is not unique

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables that collect records of event on points.

```
CREATE TABLE report_one
(
  date timestamp,
  point_id bigint,
  income int
 )
CREATE TABLE report_two
(
  date timestamp,
  point_id bigint,
  spent int
 )
```

I want to generate a sum report (and addiitonal reports). i want to use join because i need to support pagination, ordering ...

The problem is that the join key (point id for the report) is not 1:1 , so i got the same row more than one.

```
insert into report_one values('2013-1-1',1,1)
insert into report_two values('2013-1-1',1,1)
insert into report_two values('2013-1-2',1,1)

select * from report_one r1 left join report_two r2 on r1.point_id  = r2.point_id
```

will have 2 rows of table report_one ,but for total i need only one.
I want to be able to create a view of some kind of join between the tables, where each row will be only once.

**I want output like this:

1 (pid) ,  1,1,0,0 -  this from report_one

1 (pid) ,0,0,1,1 -- this from report_two

1 (pid) ,0,0,1,1   -- this from report_two **

Union all can be great , but i dont have the same columns types in the two tables.

Ps . The real table has lots of column and pk is more than one column , i just make is simple for the question

Comment: what is the expected output data you are looking for?

Comment: I added expected output

Comment: Any reason why you can't have a report_id instead of creating table per report? Then you do not need to join and can group by report_id?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the following.

```
CREATE TABLE report
(
  report_id bigint,
  date varchar(20),
  point_id bigint,
  amount int,
  amount_type varchar(20)
 );
```

THEN

```
   insert into report values (1,'2013-01-01',1,1,'income');
   insert into report values (2,'2013-01-01',1,1,'expense');
   insert into report values (2,'2013-01-02',1,1,'expense');
```

Finally

```
SELECT report_id,amount_type,SUM(point_id) FROM report GROUP BY report_id,amount_type
```

The output will sum point_id per report/amount_type then it will be easier to draw stats per date range, etc and overhead by create table and joins will also be minimized.

**The output: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f4fb/4)**

Comment: I cannot change the tables. this is what i have - 2 tables that holding events data.

Answer (score 0):

You could group tables by point_id first, choosing more appropriate aggregate functions for the fields needed and then join to each other:

```
select r1.point_id, r1.date, r1.income, r2.spent
from
(
   select point_id, max(date) date, sum(income) income
   from report_one
   group by point_id
) r1 
    inner join
    (
       select point_id, max(date) date, sum(spent) spent
       from report_two
       group by point_id
    ) r2 on r1.point_id = r2.point_id
```

Also, UNION way:

```
select point_id, date, income sum, 1 is_income
   from report_one
union all
select point_id, date, spent sum, 0 is_income
       from report_two
```

Comment: 10x, but i want a view with all records . on the view i do the totals, because there are some reports that i need to do. so first need to generate view with all records from the 2 tables.

Comment: Then UNION seems to be more appropriate.

select point_id, max(date) date, sum(income) sum, 1 is_income
   from report_one
union all
select point_id, max(date) date, sum(spent) sum, 0 is_income
       from report_two

Comment: The " also union way " in the answer is not the same that you wrote in  the comment, which is the correct and why do you need the is_income flag?

Comment: In the comment I forget to remove grouping functions (max, sum). I can't change comment so I decided to add it to answer. "is_income" field used to distinct money earned from spent, which will be in one field "sum" after union.

Comment: i think its not a good way to have this flag , look what i did in my own answer.

Comment: Anyway there will be two fields. Your answer is ok, but take in account that union can create integer field in resulting table for income (by first value - 0) and dismiss decimal part of values in next table.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can work for me:

```
select date d1,point_id p1,0 income ,spent spent from report_one
union ALL
select date d2,point_id p2,income,0 spent from report_two
```

I dont have to have the zero . I added them for demo a case that they the columns are not from the same type